# I can only change the ID of the first select of my cloned divs

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a div in html with a select inside which i am cloning every time i click the addMaterial () button, the jQuery code works as follows, i create the cloning I change the ID name of the div being cloned (that works perfect) and at the same time i also change the name of the select ID that contains that div. The problem is that only the ID of the select of the first click changes (that is, the first cloning) in the following the ID of the select keeps it by default. A clarification $ num is a variable i passed from the laravel controller with a value of 0.

**Code Html div and select**

```
  <div id="div-materiales-{{$num}}" class="form-group">
    <label>Artículos</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control widthInput articulo-{{$num}}" id="articulo-{{$num}}" name="articulo-{{$num}}">
            @foreach ($articulos as $articulo)

            <option value="{{$articulo->id}}">{{ $articulo->codigo.". ".$articulo->descripcion }}</option>

            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg" id="addMaterial" type="button">+ Añadir concepto</button>
```

**Code jQuery**

```
var i = 1;          
$( "#addMaterial" ).click(function() {

    $('#div-materiales-{{$num}}').clone().appendTo('#material-form').prop('id', 'div-materiales-' + i);

    $("#articulo-{{$num}}").removeAttr("id");
    $("#articulo-{{$num}}").attr("id","articulo-" + i);


    i++; 

    });
```

Here in the image you can check how the first cloning has changed the id of the select to article-1 but the following ones no longer do it and by default it puts article-0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQR3A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your cloning process. You clone the first container and immediatly append it to your page. That way you have now 2 select elements with the `articulo-{{$num}}` ID on your page. Then you do this:

```
// Select the select element (but now there are two, so you get only the first of your original container)
$("#articulo-{{$num}}").removeAttr("id");
// you remove the id from it !!

// and now you try to select that element again ... but  since you deleted the ID
// on the previous element, you now select the - by chance - right element in 
// your cloned container.
$("#articulo-{{$num}}").attr("id","articulo-" + i);
```

The next time you try to clone that element, there is no element with the `#articulo-{{$num}}` left, instead your select in that element and all your clones - beside the first -  does not have an ID atribute. So your selection will be empty.

**Replace**

```
$("#articulo-{{$num}}").removeAttr("id");
$("#articulo-{{$num}}").attr("id","articulo-" + i);
```

**with**

```
$('#div-materiales-' + i).find('select').attr('id', "articulo-" + i);
```

Side note:
You would not need to remove the id element if your only goal is to replace it.

Comment: A question if I want to differentiate the id to change as it would be, that is to say I have two selects of your mode it changes the name of both of them how can I distinguish them and not take all the default selects

Comment: ok thanks i solved it :  $('#div-materiales-' + i).find('select','impuestos1{{$num}}').attr('name', "impuestos1-" + i);

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question. If you have multiple selects within the `#div-materiales-' + i` you would typically select that by either name or class. So e.g. `$('#div-materiales-' + i).find('select[name=myName]')`  or `$('#div-materiales-' + i).find('select.myClass')`